# Jquery Ui modal open doubleclick on row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to open Jquery ui modal with doubleclicking on tables row.

For now I open modal with a button:

```
    $('button.adminModal').on("click", function (event) { loadDialog(this, event, '#adminPanel'); });
```

Function loadDialog opens modal with given href.

How can I open modal by doubleclicking on tables row?

I have tried using event ondblclick in  tag, but it did not worked.

LoadDialog function:

```
function loadDialog(tag, event, target) {

                event.preventDefault();
                var $loading = $('');
                var $url = $(tag).attr('href');
                var $title = $(tag).attr('title');
                var $dialog = $('<div></div>');
                $dialog.empty();
                $dialog
                    .append($loading)
                    .load($url)
                    .dialog({
                        autoOpen: false
                        , title: $title
                        , width: 500
                        , modal: true
                        , minHeight: 200
                        , show: 'fade'
                    });
};
```

Comment: Gotta show us more code man! Also this is not model-view related so will remove that tag.

Comment: Try http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/

Comment: What @Justinas has said.  Without your HTML it's hard to advise more.

Comment: so basically you want to make table row clickable

Comment: did u check my answer >?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code seems to work fine (see jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/darevskaya/NEbJV/):

```
$( "tr" ).on("dblclick", function(event) { loadDialog(this, event, '#adminPanel'); });
```

However if rows are added dynamically after the event was added it won't work.

in this case, event delegation could help:

```
 $( "table" ).on("dblclick", "tr", function(event) { loadDialog(this, event, '#adminPanel'); });
```

Answer (score 1):

check this

```
<tbody>
       <tr class='clickableRow' >
                        <td>Blah Blah</td>
                        <td>1234567</td>
                        <td>£158,000</td>
        </tr>
</tbody>

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $( ".clickableRow" ).dblclick(function(event) {
    loadDialog(this, event, '#adminPanel');
    });

});
```

OR

```
$('#thetable').find('tr').dblclick( function(){

});
```

Comment: +1 yep looks correct to me but means they need to add a class to every row.

Comment: $('#thetable').find('tr').dblclick( function(){
     
    });